# Skill vs. Luck, the ratio and its measurement

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

Gamer buddies, is there a term to describe the level of variance in a game, in comparison to luck. The card game war would have 0 skill and 1.0 luck because the player cannot affect the game. I can't think of something that has 1.0 skill. At first I thought Spelling Bee, but the words chosen for each contestant is randomly chosen suggesting some luck involved... What ratios do different games have, and how can those ratios be accurately measured? What metrics could be used to accurately measure such a ratio? I'd also like to hear of any 1.0 skill games if anyone can think of one.

To reiterate the question clearly:  does there exist such a measurement and if so what is it? Furthermore is there a term for the target of this measurement, so we can have a discussion using a noun.

EDIT: the term luck is used to describe the level of effect that chance, i.e. random events, have in affecting who the winner is. I appreciate everyone's responses.

Comment: Seems like a pretty broad question. Maybe you should ask in chat. It's a very discussion oriented question.

Comment: @Byte56 Well potentially that is true I suppose, but to directly ask in chat implies that there exists no such term, and no concrete method of measurement. Which is not what I am hoping for.

Comment: This question may get better results if you present an actual problem that you're trying to solve, with things you've tried and what you hope to find, instead of fishing for hard metrics in a very squishy field like design =)

Comment: The problem is to categorize games along a skill spectrum based on the fundamental nature of the game. Much in the same way computer scientists have decomposed computational problems into P, NP, NP-Complete, NP-Hard, etc.  Make the spectrum, define how to measure objects on the spectrum, look for similar underlying characteristics.

Comment: Chess is a game that's a 1.0 for skill and a 0.0 for luck. Skill there is measured with the [Elo rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system). However, once you have any random elements in a game, the ratio between skill and luck becomes very blurred. Even the Elo system is just an *attempt* to quantify (a) skill. I've not heard of any such systems that try the same for luck. Without being able to quantify both using a universal metric, there's no such thing as a ratio between the two.

Comment: See this duplicate question asked for board games: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9697/how-to-measure-luck-vs-skill-in-games

Comment: @Byte56: I disagree, the luck of *black vs white* is substantial, and the luck of *did I prep the right openings, etc, for this opponent* also substantial. Consider that world chess championships are routinely best of 12 games, each several hours long, so the authorities who run chess championships at this level clearly feel the need to eliminate a luck component, as evidenced by the unusually low occurrence of 7-0 scores in such championships.

Comment: "*is there a term to describe the level of variance in a game, in comparison to luck*" The question presupposes an obligate condition that "luck" and "skill" exist in a linear combination, such that having some of one naturally detracts from the other. There is no reason to make such an assumption. Furthermore, it would be impossible to "compute" such things, as it requires that game design is somehow quantifiable. Which it is most assuredly not.

Comment: @mwjohnson: "*Much in the same way computer scientists have decomposed computational problems into P, NP, NP-Complete, NP-Hard, etc.*" Those are based on objective criteria which are inherent to the problems in question. They're also not *numbers*; they're discrete categories of problems. What you're looking for has nothing to do with that sort of categorization.

Comment: @Byte56 So is checkers, ping pong, tennis, hockey, FPS that _don't_ have random spawn items enabled, RTS's that don't have random spawn.  Basically random spawn is what introduces _luck_ there, whether it's a deck of cards or items coming in outta nowhere.

Comment: Preparing for a game is part of the skill. @bobobobo Checkers, yes. Ping-pong, tennis, etc., no. There are random elements the players have no control over, wind changes, manufacturing defects in the balls of paddles/rackets. FPSs have lag, fractional timing differences, etc. I'd argue that only games that are turn based and not involving physics could qualify (as solely skill based).

Comment: @Byte56 Part of skill in games like these is _accounting_ for external factors. I think "manufacturing defect" won't tip the scales for one player of even marginally less skill than another.

Comment: @Nicol I added an edit about luck being the amount of effect on a game. Skill being the inverse. Meaning any portion of the game not accounted for by chance, is accounted for by the performance of a player. These can lie on the same dimension, and as defined the inverse, do detract from one another. Guess the coin flip, has 0 skill, and 1 luck.Checkers is a counter example, 1 skill and 0 chance. No random event takes place in checkers. Poker has some percent of game events affected by chance, given optimal play, a poker player may still lose x%, due to the affect of random chance or 'luck'.

Comment: @Nicol Np-* point: Given discrete turn games like checkers, and continuous "time" games like tennis, I think an objective set of criteria to describe the nature of a game may emerge. The distinction between different classes of games will be necessary, because some classes of games will have a set of statements you can make about them while others will not, as they are of a different class. I use the NP problems as an example of how different problem classes and subclassses (NP-hard, NP-Easy, Complete, etc.) emerged, as I expect this game categorization problem to follow a similar evolution.

Comment: You cant realy measure skill, let alone doing that accurately, as you would have to have a universal definition of a unit of skill. How would you compare ones chess playing skills to his basketball playing skills? Note, that  basketball is a teamgame. How does ones skill affect the teams chances of winning?
But then again, why would you even need that measure and why would you need it to be percise? Im guessing this is a bit of an XY problem. Tell us what your actual problem is, and we might find a better solution than thinking of an absolute skill measure

Answer (score 6):

*This answer assume familiarity with [normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and standard deviations.*

A simple but usually reasonable assumption is that we can describe the outcome of a game as a random event where player1 wins if player1's skill plus a normal distributed random variable is greater than player2's skill. The standard deviation of that normal distribution can be compared to the difference between the two player's skills, and for a larger group of players we can compare the standard deviation of the normal distribution to the standard deviation of the skill levels of that player group.

Thus if we for instance have a group of players where the standard deviation of those players's skills is double the standard deviation of the luck of the game we could with some reason say that the game for this group is 1/3 luck and 2/3 skill, but this is only valid for that specific group of players, there is no universal way to measure luck versus skill in a game.

### Edit: Some examples to illustrate the difficulties of the question

All games for two players.

**Flip and choose**
First a coin is flipped to determine who goes first, then each player in turn choose a number from 1 to 10. Whoever choose the biggest number wins, in case of a draw the player who started wins.

**Gomoku with coin flip**
First a coin is flipped to determine who goes first, then the players play a standard match of Gomoku on a 15x15 board, whoever wins that game wins.

#### Analysis

Intuitively we'd say that Flip and choose is a game of luck, an average person would figure the optimal play before even playing a single round, so effectively the coin flip is all that matters.

Gomoku is game of skill, an average person will not be able to produce optimal play. Still, starting is an advantage so at least the flip of the coin must count for some luck in the final verdict.

With optimal play Gomoku is a win for the player who goes first, it is also a solved game, so a computer equipped with the solution database will always win if it is allowed to go first. Thus to computer players both games are trivial extensions to a standard coin flip, whoever wins the flip wins the game. This would suggest that they are both games of 100% luck. To reach any other conclusion we must consider a player base of less skill.

Comment: I believe you overstate your case in the second paragraph. While the level of play influences the details of the calculation, and hence the result, the method itself doesn't change. I believe OP is looking for a measurement at some sort of *standard level of play*, let's call it *good club player* for sake of starting the discussion.

Comment: I know, the above sounds rather vague. I counter that the solution to all complex problems starts vague, and becomes clearer as the solution slowly acquires its final shape.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I believe that I phrase it quite accurately, there is no universal way. But we still may be able to find a suitable terran method for selecting a representative player group for determining a ratio.

Comment: That's more like it!

Comment: I am not so interested in rating players but rating games themselves. Checkers for example is a solved game, so if two players play optimally, player two always wins, or maybe p1, I can't remember right now. Something like guess the coin flip has no skill playing a role in determining the winner.

Comment: @mwjohnson It is possible to determine that some games like guess the coin flip is always 100% luck, but look at your own comment, in order to use Checkers as an example you had to include the skill of some players, you simply can't make the argument without including players and their specific skill and way of playing the game. (It is stalemate by the way.)

Comment: @eBusiness I think we are in agreement. In the case of Checkers, naturally not all players know all optimal moves, but that doesn't mean the role of luck plays any more importance in the game. For our measure, it is still a 1.0 skill game, 0.0 luck game, as there are no events affected by chance. Games like Magic the gathering, most other card or dice games, have some portion of the game determined by the "luck" of the draw or roll of the dice. For those games the affect of luck is probably more complicated to calculate.

Comment: To calculate the affect of luck, a simple model might be the percent of all events in the game which are random events, multiplied by some weight which is based on the "strength" of that event in the game. For a match of blackjack (21), a draw card event has some amount of influence in determining the winner. A betting event does as well. My guess is that 21 only has two types of events, one of which is of random type. Success in betting is the skill portion of the game. How important each of those is in determining a winner might be harder to say...Pros probably say it is nearly all skill. :)

Comment: @mwjohnson I don't think you get it yet. Checkers for sufficiently skilled computers is hardly a game as it always ends in draw with neither skill nor luck doing anything to sway the result. In my extension I use Gomoku as a stand in for Checkers as that game posses similar game theoretical properties bot solves to the first mover winning.

Comment: @ebusiness I believe I do get it. The nature of the game, the amount of random events that take place vs. The number of "skill" based events does not change based on the player. Just because two perfect players of checkers make the game boring, much like adults playing tictactoe, doesn't change the nature of the game. It is still comprised of the same amount of random events and player decisions.

Comment: @ebusiness the point about gomoku is a great and interesting one. I feel for solved games, the level of "fun" is zero given optimal play, granted generally that optimal play is likely restricted to computers for the complicated games.

Comment: @mwjohnson How would you rate Flip and choose? It has a luck based event and a skill based event. If you simply count events this can't be all luck.

Comment: @eBusiness Let me clarify a point about Flip & Choose. After the coin flip, the players keep their choice secret, by for example writing on paper, and reveal at the same time? If p1 wins the toss, they should always choose 10. They will either win, for choosing the larger number or win for having a tie...

Comment: I find your last couple of paragraphs confusing. You seem to reach the conclusion that any game becomes 100% luck when played between players of equal skill. That's just a tautology, since you've explicitly removed the effect of skill on on how the game is played. A 100% luck game is one that by definition can have no winning strategy. Choices the player makes cannot affect their chance of winning. Both "flip and choose" and Gomoku have meaningful choices that the player can make, meaning those games are not 100% luck.

Answer (score 2):

> does there exist such a measurement and if so what is it?

**No**, no such measurement exists. While you may be able to come up with a metric for skill. You'll be hard pressed to come up with a metric for luck (unless it's *controlled* luck). However, the two metrics would likely be different enough that you're essentially taking the ratio of apples/oranges. Further, the metrics will vary from game to game, so comparing ratios between two games is comparing apples/oranges to GI Joes/cats.

However, there are ways to decide if a game is a game of skill or a game of chance, at least from juridical point of view. Specifically, gambling in law. A number of states in the US allow people to pay money to enter games of skill, but not games of chance (or at least significantly limit the amount of money that can be spent on games of chance). There is [a paper](http://ideas.repec.org/p/ner/tilbur/urnnbnnlui12-140730.html) on the topic, but the [All Games of Chance](http://allgamesofchance.com/skill-or-chance-games.htm) website has a decent definition of how these are legally categorized:

> There are two main differences between games of chance and games of
>   skill. The first difference is who the player is playing against. When
>   a player is playing against the house, it is a game of chance. When
>   the player is pitted against other players, it is considered to be a
>   game of skill. Also, if an individual can prove that a particular game
>   involves the use of skill like strategies, statistics or math along
>   with a factor of luck or chance, the game would be allowed and would
>   be categorized as game of skill.

Comment: As Canadian Bridge Champion and barrister Eric Murray is reputed to have argued in the case of **Regina vs St. Clair Bridge Club**: "Bridge is only a game of chance when it is played as the justices of the Ontario Supreme Court play it [in chambers]." As the St. Clair Bridge Club still runs rubber bridge for high stakes several decades later, I will take it that they won that case.

Answer (score 1):

An important point to remember is that the importance of skill vs luck in determining the winner of a match increases as the number of *games* in a match increases. For example, this is why golf tournaments are 4 days long; the influence of luck (at the PGA level of play) is simply too great over a mere 18 holes.

This then provides a means of measuring the relative importance of luck vs skill: the number of matches (or alternatively, hours played) required to accurately determine the better player with a given statistical confidence. (95% would be the usual standard in such a case, as in the familiar *19 times out of 20*.)

Then we get:

1. Golf would be rated at 16 *rounds* (of 18 holes) or 64 hours (16 rounds of *4 standard hours* play) if you take the FedEx playoffs as the standard to accurately rate the players.
2. Backgammon is usually played to *best of 21* I believe in tournament play, but individual games would be averaging 2 or 3 due to the doubling cube. It's rating would then be about 7 - 10 matches, but only perhaps the same 7 - 10 hours.
3. Duplicate bridge would be rated about 2 sessions of 4 hours each, looking at the elimination rounds of larger team events like Vanderbilt and Spingold.
4. Chess world championships are regularly best of 12 (and I believe Go championships are similar).

Noting particularly from the latter point, even such seminal games of skill as Chess and Go are believed to possess a considerable element of luck *per individual game*, when played at a professional level. This would seem to be borne out by the extreme rarity of *sweeps* in such competitions.

**Update**:
A confound when using *number of hours of play* is that organizing committees may have unstated reasons for extending the length of individual games. My personal belief is that the overall quality of chess games at the world level would not decrease much if the allotted time were halved. However, there seems to be the unstated intent to showcase **all** of the individual games as *best instances* of play, leading to the players having more clock time than might be strictly necessary to determine the best player. (This is not necessarily wrong, simply a complication to note when measuring relative importance of skill vs luck.)

For example, Chess and Go matches extend to an almost obscene number of hours, clearly more than necessary to determine the best player given the, both believed and evidenced, high ratio of skill to luck even in individual games. If the sole purpose of world championship matches were the determination of the best player, the number of play hours, and possibly the number of games, could be reduced for both of these games.

Comment: I think you're confusing "luck" with "ability to reproduce the successful outcome".  "Luck" in the question referred to an advantage that you never trained or worked to get -- you just literally got handed "the good card".  You are classifying "lucky shots" under "luck", which I wouldn't -- I would classify an unlikely hole in one as _skill_, not _luck_ (since the player must have trained to be able to do that).

Comment: @bobobobo: Strange. My mother played golf regularly for years with a woman who averaged better than one hole-in-one a year. Her comment on them was that every single one was a badly-hit shot that got lucky.

Comment: Yeah yeah. That's what people say to be modest.  I personally always hated it when my 3-pointers were called _lucky_, while I would always want to chalk them up to _skill_.

Comment: 3-pointers are skill, because you aim at the basket (and choose your floor spot carefully). Holes-in-one are luck because (usually, in tournaments at least), the pin placements are such that only weak players aim at the pin. The strong players are fading or drawing to ensure that a miss is into a safe area to save par from.

Comment: I do agree that there is something to be said about skill ending at the same point intent does, and luck beginning. At the same time, I've only played golf once, and not once was my ball ever even near the green let alone the hole, so I will argue it does take skill to get a hole-in-one. Whether that was the precise intent of the player at the time is another story.

Comment: @mwjohnson: Getting the ball consistently on the green is skill; getting the hole-in-one is luck. Tiger Woods has exactly 2 in his PGA career, both **prior** to his Master's win in 1997.: http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/sports/golf/pga/2006-07-16-aces-chron.htm

Comment: @PieterGeerkens My primary point is that if I lack the skill to get the ball on the green, by definition it is impossible for me to get a hole in one, as the hole is on the green. So luck alone is not sufficient to score a hole-in-one.

Comment: @mwjohnson: He said *consistently* on the green. Anyone can get it there once in a while. It takes skill to do so with any regularity.

Answer (score 1):

Back-of-the-Napkin approach:

1. Need a larger sample size and longer time series than you probably would suspect intuitively.
2. K.I.S.S.: How quickly do the winners and losers "revert to the mean?" If the mean "reversion/regression" is slow then skill plays a larger roll.  If mean "reversion/regression" is fast then luck plays a more significant role in the outcome(s).
3. If the game is digital, and the code is locked, then trying to tease apart luck from skill is a waste of your time, since any algorithm imaginable could be shaping the outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

Some measures have been proposed, see

- ["On a relative measure of skill for games with chance elements"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02579073)
- ["A new relative skill measure for games with chance elements"](https://doi.org/10.1002/mde.1147)

The basic idea from the first paper is to estimate

`skill = (potential learning effect) / (potential learning effect + potential random effect)`

which gives skill as a number between 0 and 1. Alas, these effects are analytically computable only for "easy" games. For a one-player game, the above equation comes down to

`skill = (Gm - G0) / (Gu - G0)`

where the G's are the expected net gains of three players

> - '0': a beginner who plays the game in the naive way of somebody who has
>     just mastered the rules of the game.
> - 'm': a real average player who can be thought to represent the vast majority
>     of players.
> - 'u': a virtual average player whom we tell in advance (i.e. before he has
>     to decide) the outcome of the chance elements.

As an example they calculate for American Roulette: Gu = 35 and Gm = -1/74, the latter corresponding a "simple" play (e.g. rouge/noir,
pair/impair). The value for G0 is actually a matter of debate, even for this game. If the beginner goes for a simple strategy, then the skill is 0 obviously. However if G0 is for a non-simple strategy (e.g. [plein, cheval, carre](http://www.casino-zen.com/mises-gains-roulette.html)), then G0 is -1/37 (i.e. worse average loss.) So with the latter assumption, there is a minor potential for learning, so skill is 0.0004. I have to say I'm a little miffed that they use French terminology for the American Roulette; alas they source they cite for further details is in Dutch.

For Blackjack they derive from a computer simulation that Gm = 0.11, Gu = 27, and take G0 = -0.057 for a "mimic the dealer" strategy, and from that obttain a skill of 0.006.

For games where players compete directly and strategies like sandbagging or bluffing matter (these are the only games called multi-player games in game theory by the way), the second paper has a more sensible approach in that it considers players potentially changing strategy a source of randomness. They use the same skill formula as above (except that they calll the three types of players beginner, optimal and fictive player). The difference in their approach is that

> the expected gains for player i as an optimal player
>   are given by his expected gains in the Nash
>   equilibrium of the related two-person zero-sum
>   game against the coalition of the other players

and for the "fictive" player they also assume that he knows the the outcome of the
randomization process of his opponents.

Alas there aren't any examples that are intersting but simple enough to relate in detail here. They compute for a simplified version of drawpoker a skill of 0.22.

Both papers emphasise however that the exact skill value depends on the definition/assumption of beginners’ behavior.

An experimental approach is needed for more complex games of practical interest, e.g.

- ["The Role of Skill Versus Luck in Poker: Evidence from the World Series of Poker"](http://www.nber.org/papers/w17023)

> Those players identified a priori as being highly skilled achieved an average return on investment of over 30 percent, compared to a -15 percent for all other players. This large gap in returns is strong evidence in support of the idea that poker is a game of skill.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt: I was going to. Is this site Latex-enabled? I'm struggling to type in any equations here.

Comment: [Not yet](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/can-we-enable-mathjax-on-gdse-revisited), sorry :/

Comment: This is an excellent response, thank you for your contribution. It's interesting to see how little skill is involved in some of those classic casino games; makes sense, economically.